# Adding column to another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of three numbers that are the percent difference of other numbers.

The query I've used looks like this:

```
select abs((((select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File1') - 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File2')) / 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File2'))*100)
union all
select abs((((select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File3') - 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File4')) / 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File4'))*100)
union all
select abs((((select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File5') - 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File6')) / 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File6'))*100)
```

which results in a table like this:

```
| (No column name) |
|:----------------:|
|             1.54 |
|             1.15 |
|             2.04 |
```

These numbers are the percent difference for a category of data from three files. These file names are `Column1` in `Table1`. How could I write this query so that the table looks like this instead? (Add the file names in a column to the left of these numbers).

```
| FileName | (No column name) |
|:--------:|:----------------:|
| File1    |             1.54 |
| File2    |             1.15 |
| File3    |             2.04 |
```

Comment: add column 1 to each query and group by column1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the file name to the query:

```
select FileName='File1', PCT_DIFF=abs((((select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File1') - 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File2')) / 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File2'))*100)
union all
select 'File3', abs((((select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File3') - 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File4')) / 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File4'))*100)
union all
select 'File5', abs((((select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File5') - 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File6')) / 
    (select avg(Number) from Table1 where File='File6'))*100)
```

Comment: I'm a dolt. I've done this before. I don't know why I didn't think of this. Thank you for unclogging my brain.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the query!

```
select file,
       100 * (prev_avg - avg) / avg as percent_diff
from (select file, avg(Number) as avg,
             lag(avg(Number)) over (order by file) as prev_avg
      from table1
      where file in ('File1', 'File2', 'File3', 'File4', 'File5', 'File6')
      group by file
     ) t
where file in ('File2', 'File4', 'File6');
```

This assumes that the files are ordered by name.  If should be easy to modify if they are ordered in some other way -- say by date or size.

This also readily generalizes to additional rows.